# AzureFileCopy produces application/octet-stream files in blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am using the AzureFileCopy task to copy files to a blob for a cdn, but all my new files end up as application/octet-stream by default. Is there any way this can be changed?

```
steps:
- task: AzureFileCopy@1
  displayName: ' File Copy - blob'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xxxxxx/blob'
    azureSubscription: 'xxxxxx'
    Destination: AzureBlob
    storage: xxxxxx
    ContainerName: cdn
```

Comment: It's not hard to manually change them but annoying

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading to the latest task version (V5), Azure File Copy will set the content types by default for destination type Blob.

Answer (score 0):

AzCopy sets the content type for a blob or file to application/octet-stream by default. You can set the content type for all blobs or files by explicitly specifying a value for this option.

If you specify this option without a value, then AzCopy sets each blob or file's content type according to its file extension. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#setcontenttypecontent-type for more details.

Comment: I am not using AzCopy, the question relates to the AzureFileCopy task

Comment: @RobSedgwick The Azure File Copy task uses AzCopy command on agent, on a powershell